# Typescript: Define if property should be included based on value of other property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript with React and struggling to get a type correct.. What I am trying to achieve is that for the interface Car the property **colorId** is required if **carColor** is **'blue'** otherwise it should not be included. Any feedback on how to achieve this?

```
interface Car {
    carBrand: string;
    carColor: 'black' | 'blue';
    colorId?: string;
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/N713RW). `carColor`  acts a role of discriminant. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics and `Omit`.

Create a `BaseCar` interface that has `carBrand`, `carColor` and `carId` properties and then create a `Car` type that conditionally decides the `colorId` property.

```
interface BaseCar {
  carBrand: string;
  carColor: "black" | "blue";
  colorId: string;
}

type Car<T> = T extends "black" ? Omit<BaseCar, "colorId"> : BaseCar;

const blueCar: Car<"blue"> = {
  carBrand: "tesla",
  carColor: "blue",
  colorId: "123",
};

const blackCar: Car<"black"> = {
  carBrand: "honda",
  carColor: "black",
};

// @ts-expect-error
const blueCarWithoutId: Car<"blue"> = {
  carBrand: "tesla",
  carColor: "blue",
};

const blackCarWithId: Car<"black"> = {
  carBrand: "honda",
  carColor: "black",
  // @ts-expect-error
  colorId: "123",
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
type CarColors = "black" | "blue";

// create generic that passed color as asgument
interface Car<C extends CarColors = "black"> {
  carBrand: string;
  carColor: C;
  colorId: string;
}

// create conditional type that omits carColor when color is black
type ColoredCar<C extends CarColors = "black"> = C extends "blue" ? Car<"blue"> : Omit<Car, "carColor">;

// use agrument blue to require color
const myCar: ColoredCar<"blue"> = {
  carBrand: "bmw",
  carColor: "blue",
  colorId: "123"
};

// otherwise it is omitted 
const myCar2: ColoredCar = {
  carBrand: "bmw",
  colorId: "123"
};
```

Comment: `colorId` on `Car` shouldn't be optional. Remove `colorId` from `myCar` and TS wouldn't complain because it's an optional field. I think the OP wants `colorId` to be present for blue cars.